# Ubuntu gnome package installation error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, dpkg, debugger

When trying to install insight from some ppa repositories i get these errors.

```
sudo apt-get install insight
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  insight
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,298 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,787 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  insight
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
(Reading database ... 232356 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../insight_6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking insight (6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1) ...
```

-----Here are the problems-------

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/insight_6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libinproctrace.so', which is also in package gdbserver 7.8-1ubuntu4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/insight_6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: i have already tried sudo apt-get install -f

Answer (score 0):

Run this command first:

```
dpkg -l | grep libinproctrace
```

if you find any output then remove it using this command

```
dpkg -r packagename
```

After running this command , run:

```
apt-get update
```

Then you will be able to install any new packages. If you find any issue Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

run this:  sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop then 
accept the 3rd solution and it will work. warning it will downgrade 3 packages.

Comment: What third solution? Your answer lacks clarity and detail. Please use the EDIT button to improve it.